# Entrywise Conversion from Matrix of Integers to Matrix of Reciprocals

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose I have a matrix where $x  \in \mathbb{Z}$

$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots  & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots  & x_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    x_{d1} & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots  & x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}$

what is the best way to arrive at the following matrix:

$ B = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{x_{11}} & \frac{1}{x_{12}} & \frac{1}{x_{13}} & \dots  & \frac{1}{x_{1n}} \\
    \frac{1}{x_{21}} & \frac{1}{x_{22}} & \frac{1}{x_{23}} & \dots  & \frac{1}{x_{2n}} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \frac{1}{x_{d1}} & \frac{1}{x_{d2}} & \frac{1}{x_{d3}} & \dots  & \frac{1}{x_{dn}}
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Find the reciprocal of each element.

Comment: yes...how would you write this?

Comment: "Find the reciprocal of each element."

Comment: I don't suppose i can write $1/A$

Comment: "Find the reciprocal of each element."

Comment: "$B$ is the matrix of the reciprocal of each element in $A$"

Comment: is there no matrix manipulation that can be written in a mathematical form

Comment: I don't think there is such a manipulation.

Comment: Let's clear something up. In matrices $A$ and $B$ we have: $x_{11}=x_{11}$, $x_{12}=x_{12}$, etc.? In other words, is @KennyLau 's comment true?

Comment: my understanding $x_{11} \neq x_{11}$ in terms of the element values in $A, B$

Comment: there is a bijective mapping of $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @TsTeaTime, then your question is not well defined. I could just write any matrix of reciprocals with no relation to the elements of $A$ and call it $B$. Especially when you ask "what is the best way to arrive at the following matrix"

Comment: okay i understand what you are getting at

Comment: there is a bijective mapping of the elements $A_{ij}$ to $B_{ij}$. Is this the correct way to explain this?

Comment: Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the Schur product (sometimes also called Hadamard product) as follows:

If $A, B \in \mathbb K^{n \times m}$ then the Schurproduct $A \ast B$ is defined as $(A \ast B)_{i,j} = (A)_{i,j} (B)_{i,j}$, i.e. the multiplication of the entries.

Using that you can say the following:

"Let $B$ the inverse of $A$ respecting the Schur product."

Comment: Wonderful...thank you for this @Yaddle. This is really helpful!

Comment: Does $\mathbb K^{n \times m}$ represent anything in particular? i am not able to find this under the list of Number Sets?

Comment: In my notation you have $\mathbb K \in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C\}$ and $\mathbb K^{n \times m}$ denotes the space of matrices with $n$ rows and $m$ columns with entries in $\mathbb K$. Hope that makes it a little clearer :)